# How to call a method every x seconds in Objective-C using NSTimer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I am using Objective-C, Xcode 4.5.1 and working on an app for the iPhone.

I have a method A in which I want to call another method B to do a series of calculations every x seconds. In method A I start playing an audio file. Method B will monitor the audio every x seconds for the duration of the audio file.

I have found `NSTimer` as a potential solution, but am having a hard time getting it to work/understanding it.

I simply want to call Method B every x seconds and run its calculations, but `NSTimer` requires me to provide several things of which I'm not sure what I'm supposed to tell it.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval) 
target:(id) select:(SEL) userInfo:(id) repeats:(BOOL)];
```

It is my understanding that at `NSTimeInterval` I provide the interval at which I want `NSTimer` to operate. But, how do I tell it to run Method B?

I have looked at example code, and am currently under the impression that I provide the method at the '`select:`'. But, what do I write at the '`target:`'? Why would I need a target? I tried entering '`self`', but Xcode tells me:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'self'

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self 
select:@selector(targetMethod:myVolumeMonitor()) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

So, I figure '`self`' is supposed to be a pointer to an object, but where do I want to point to?

Below is a simplification of my code:

```
MethodA()
{
//Start playing an audio file.

//NSTimer calling Method B, as long the audio file is playing, every x seconds.
}

MethodB()
{
//Do calculations.
}
```

I would be grateful if somebody could provide me with some answers/point me in the right direction! (:

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Target is the recipient of the message named in select. 
In Objective-C functions are not called. There are rather messages sent to objects. The Object internally refers to its symbol table and determines which of its methods is being called. That is a selector. Your selector is `@selector(MethodB)`. 
(BTW: you should start method names with lower case. "methodB" would be more appropriate here.) 
This leads to the question: how to determine the object to which the message is sent? That is the target. In your case, it is simply `self`.

BTW: In this case the selector is expected to return void and accept an id, which is the id of the NSTimer object itself. That will come handy if you want the timer to stop firing based on some conditions according to your program logic. 
Most important: Your selector is then `methodB:` rather than `methodB`.

```
- (void) methodA
{
//Start playing an audio file.

//NSTimer calling Method B, as long the audio file is playing, every 5 seconds.
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f 
target:self selector:@selector(methodB:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) methodB:(NSTimer *)timer
{
//Do calculations.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You were a great help! I managed to figure it all out! (: @Hermann Klecker

Comment: You are welcome. If it was helpful eventaully I would not mind an 'accept' though. :)

Comment: I am using the same code but the methodB is not getting called. Here's the code                              -(void)cardTimer{
    NSLog(@"inside timer");

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.0f target: self selector: @selector(timerCalled:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];

    [timersArray addObject:timer];

    NSLog(@"timer called 1"); // getting logs till here

}



-(void)timerCalled:(NSTimer *)timer{

    NSLog(@"Timer called 2");

    isTooManyCard=false;

    [cards removeAllObjects];

    [uniquePages removeAllObjects];

}

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
 NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:(x) target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:aTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];  
    [popUpImageView release];

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer 
{
if(condition)
{
  [theTimer isValid]; //recall the NSTimer
   //implement your methods
}
else
{
  [theTimer invalidate]; //stop the NSTimer

}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well you are trying to call an normal C method, [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) can't to that.

The target is the an instance of the class on which to call the [selector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-CHDDAEIA), this selector adn not select. The selector here is a `SEL` type which you can create with the  `@selector(METHOD_NAME)` function.

For example this will call the `handleTimer :` ever 0.1 second: (For this example the AppDelegate is used):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //SNIP, some code to setup the windos.   

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    return YES;
}

- (void) handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // Hanlde the timed event.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to figure it all out! (:

Answer (score 5):

If you look at your code and compared to the one below

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
select:@selector(targetMethod:myVolumeMonitor()) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

self means that you are invoking a method in same instance of your class, in your example the method is myVolumeMonitor

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
selector:@selector(MethodB) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and you are good to go though

method be should look like this

```
- (void)MethodB:(NSTimer*)timer { 
// do something
}
```

Comment: Select is not part of the method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`, also method names should start with a lower case.

Comment: Dunno, copied this from working apps source code. Ok, yes I changed selector to select while trying to bold my answer

Comment: The method you call in the example does not exist: [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-CHDDAEIA) this what the method should be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to figure it all out! (: