# Count from 100 to 1 with a different interval

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown in Swift which do not rely on any specific time, but a time interval i choose. For an example i want the countdown from 100-99 to take approximately 4 hours. Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSTimer` to run a specific task after a given time and specify whether or not you want it to repeat itself. The method you're looking for is most likely `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. For an example, please look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454583/how-to-call-a-method-every-x-seconds-in-objective-c-using-nstimer).

For more informations, please look at Apple's [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) and especially section titled `Scheduling Timers in Run Loops`.